# Convert City field from text to Drop Down in billing address at checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.3, billing-address, field, city

i want to convert city field from text to select or drop down. i have tried many ways but unable to implement it. I want to convert city text field to select and want to show custom city option how can i achieve this any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to share the way i have achieved this task, it may help other.

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="make_list_provider" xsi:type="object">vendor\module\Model\CheckoutDetailsProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="checkout_layout_processor_changecity" type="vendor\module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> vendor\module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * Process js Layout of block
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billingAddress']['children']['billing-address-fieldset']['children']['city'] = $this->getConfig();
        return $jsLayout;
    }

    /**
     * @return $field
     */
    private function getConfig()
    {
        $field = [
            'component' => 'vendor_module/js/city',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'billingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'id' => 'city'
            ],
            'label' => 'City',
            'value' => '',
            'dataScope' => 'billingAddress.city',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 80,
            'customEntry' => null,
            'visible' => true,
            'options' => [ ],
            'filterBy' => [
                'target' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id',
                'field' => 'country_id'
            ],
            'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => true
            ],
            'id' => 'city'
        ];
        return $field;
    }
}
```

> vendor_module/js/city

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
 define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/default-post-code-resolver',
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'mage/template',
    'mage/validation',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'jquery/ui'
], function (_, registry, Select, defaultPostCodeResolver, $) {
    'use strict';

    return Select.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super()
            this.update();
            return this;
        },
        /**
         * @param {String} value
         */
        update: function () {
            var options = window.checkoutConfig.cityData.cityOpt,
            cityOptions = [];
            $.each(options, function (index, cityOptionValue) {
                    var name = cityOptionValue.name;
                    var jsonObject = {
                        value: cityOptionValue.value,
                        title: cityOptionValue.label,
                        country_id: "PK",
                        label: cityOptionValue.label
                    };
                    cityOptions.push(jsonObject);
            });
            this.setOptions(cityOptions);
        }
    });
});
```

> vendor\module\Model\CheckoutDetailsProvider

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SampleConfigProvider
 */
class CheckoutDetailsProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    protected $helper;
    public function __construct(
        \vednor\module\Helper\Data $helper    
        ){
        $this->helper = $helper; 
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    { 
        return [
            'cityData' => [
                'cityOpt' => $this->helper->getCityOptions()
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

> vednor\module\Helper\Data $helper

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    ){
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
   
    public function getCityOptions(){
         //Add your city list here
        $options = [
            '1' => [
                'value'=>'',
                'label'=>__('Please select a city.'),
            ],
            '2' => [
                'value'=>'Lahore',
                'label'=>__('Lahore'),
            ],
            '3' => [
                'value'=>'Karachi',
                'label'=>__('Karachi'),
            ]
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

> Helpful Links

1:[Magento2-City-Dropdown GitHub repository](https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown)

2:[How can I change the City Name to Drop Down on Checkout Page. Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292930/how-can-i-change-the-city-name-to-drop-down-on-checkout-page-magento-2)